# Invalid Bunifu Cast

Tags: c#, bunifu

I am trying to create a function so it gets the name of the button(sender) but I get this error.

```
System.InvalidCastException HResult=0x80004002 to cast object of type
'Bunifu.Framework.UI.BunifuFlatButton' to type
'Bunifu.UI.WinForms.BunifuButton.BunifuButton'
```

Code:

```
using Bunifu.UI.WinForms.BunifuButton;

private void Dashboard_Bt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string objname = ((BunifuButton)sender).Name;

        label1.Text = objname;
    }
```

Comment: `string objname = ((BunifuFlatButton)sender).Name;`

Comment: Thank You, BunifuFlatButton uses a different library compared to a BunifuButton BunifuButton uses Bunifu.UI.WinForms.BunifuButton and BunifuFlatButton use Bunifu.Framework.UI

Comment: i understand. The reason you're seeing that in your exception is because that is the type of button that was clicked and passed to your event handler as `sender`

Comment: @TheGamerzs The object's type is `BunifuFlatButton`, according to the exception.  What library it comes from isn't relevant.